# Confusion about OpenFileDialog

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, openfiledialog

I am following [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/mahesh/openfiledialog-in-c-sharp/) tutorial and downloaded source code to practice, and it works. The problem occurs when I rewrite the code: just one image is added instead of all the selected images. What am I doing wrong here?

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    ofd.Filter = "Images (*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF,*.PNG,*.TIFF)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG;*.TIFF|" +
"All files (*.*)|*.*";
    ofd.Multiselect = true;

    if (ofd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {

        foreach (string name in ofd.FileNames)
        {

            PictureBox imageControl = new PictureBox();
            imageControl.Width = 100;
            imageControl.Height = 100;
            Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort CallBck = new Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);
            Bitmap myBitmap = new Bitmap(name);

            Image img = myBitmap.GetThumbnailImage(97, 97, CallBck, IntPtr.Zero);
            imageControl.Image = img;
            panel1.Controls.Add(imageControl);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Very unlikely you diagnosed this problem correctly.  Practice using the debugger, you need to know how to set a breakpoint and single-step through the code.  You would then discover that the real problem doesn't have anything to do with the OpenFileDialog and have a fair shot at fixing the control code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll bet they *are* all being added but they're just all going on top of each other at location (0,0) in the panel (you should step through your code to check this though).

The solution: Either manually specify a location for each new PictureBox, or use a layout control such as a [`FlowLayoutPanel`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.flowlayoutpanel%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: I have just noticed that Writer used flowLayoutPanel